# Upload image from hard drive & Insert it into text message

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, mongodb

I wonder how to make such functionality by analogy as on stackoverflow's "ask question" page. My purpose: I have a textarea to enter message and a button "Add image" above it. On clicking the button I see the dialog with button "Choose file from hard drive". Then I choose an image with appropriate extension and the image is inserted into the message. Then I post the message and the image is seen as an image among the text.
How then images are stored in database?
What is the best approach to make such thing?
Thanks in advance.
P.S. All my messages should be stored in MongoDB. My views are JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder, name it e.g; `user_uplaods` and store image file name in DB. You already know the path where we are uploading files so no need to store path in DB. When you need to display, fetch file name from DB and attach path to display that.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly there are 3 steps:

1. Select image and upload it via HTML5 binary upload or iFrame uploader to your server.
2. Once your server has received and handled the image, throw back the image path your                        browser.
3. Display the image in your formular or wherever else - by now you should have the image url.